# Items get mixed up when changing xml attributes using the adapter class in recycle view in android

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have an adapter class which loads items dynamically and shows them in a `RecyclerView`. My problem is that when I swipe up and down the recycler view the images get mixed and are shown in wrong positions (i.e. in other item's view).

For example, I have an item X and another item Y. Now when I swipe up and down the image which was to be shown in item Y get shown in item X and the same happens with other attributes.

Here is my adapter class:

```
public class NewsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NewsAdapter.NewsViewHolder> {

   private DatabaseReference refDNewsTable= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("news_feeds");
   private StorageReference refStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl("firebase_url_comes_here");
   private Context mContext;
   private List<NewsModel> newsList;

   public class NewsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
     public TextView nHeading, nDes,nDaTi;
     public ImageView nImg;

     public NewsViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        nHeading = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_newsHeadline);
        nDes = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_nDes);
        nImg = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.iv_nImg);
        nDaTi=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_nDaTi);
    }
  }

  public NewsAdapter(Context mContext, List<NewsModel> newsList) {
     this.mContext = mContext;
     this.newsList = newsList;
  }

  @Override
  public NewsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
     View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
             .inflate(R.layout.news_model, parent, false);

     return new NewsViewHolder(itemView);
  }

  @Override
  public void onBindViewHolder(final NewsViewHolder holder, int position) {
     NewsModel news = newsList.get(position);
     holder.nHeading.setText(news.getnHeading());
     if(news.hasDes()) {
         holder.nDes.setText(news.getnDes());
     }else{
         holder.nDes.setVisibility(View.GONE);
     }
     if(news.hasImg()){
         // Reference to an image file in Firebase Storage
         StorageReference imgReference =refStorage.child(news.getnId());

         // Load the image using Glide
         Glide.with(mContext)
                 .using(new FirebaseImageLoader())
                 .load(imgReference)
                 .into(holder.nImg);
     }else{
         holder.nImg.setVisibility(View.GONE);
     }
     holder.nDaTi.setText(news.getnDaTi());
 }

 public void downloadFile(final NewsViewHolder holder){
     try {
         final File localFile = File.createTempFile("images", "jpg");
         refStorage.getFile(localFile).addOnSuccessListener(new   OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(localFile.getAbsolutePath());
                holder.nImg.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
            }
        });
     } catch (IOException e ) {}
 }

 @Override
 public int getItemCount() {
     return newsList.size();
 }
}
```

And this is my news_model.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_margin="4dp"
    card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="true"
    card_view:cardElevation="16dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="0dp">

<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@color/cBgNews"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:padding="10dp"
            card_view:cardElevation="6dp"
            card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/cNewsHeadline"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/card_des"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="0dp">

         <TextView
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:maxLines="3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/cWhite"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/tv_newsHeadline" />

      </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

      <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="#0000"
        android:paddingEnd="6dp"
        android:paddingStart="6dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

      <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxHeight="300dp"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/iv_nImg" />


           <TextView
            android:text="Description..."
            android:maxLines="8"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/cBlack"
            android:id="@+id/tv_nDes" />

         <TextView
            android:text="Date and Time"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:textColor="#999999"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:id="@+id/tv_nDaTi" />

       </LinearLayout>
     </LinearLayout>
   </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

NOTE: I am using firebase to receive the content directly and haven't created any kind of database in my app yet. i.e. it loads data every time it needs it directly in adapter class.

Comment: "please tell me why this is happening" could be a million reasons, we would need to see the relevant code. Keep it short though, make a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @weston here you have it. Check out the question now, i have added all that i could find relevant to the question. please help me if you can because everything is in chaos with this thing bugged.

Comment: try to add holder.setIsRecyclable(false); in onBindChildViewHolder(). I was facing the same issue when I was dealing with the local db.

Comment: I can't spot the problem. Please read the link I gave you: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve The very act of creating an MCVE can give you the fix. So for example, I understand this is not just images, so why are the images relevant to the problem? What is the smallest amount of code needed to expose the problem?

Comment: For all we know it's a problem in your `NewsModel`. Or maybe you are manipulating this list elsewhere. That's why the example needs to be Complete.

Comment: Be much clearer on this point, you talk about images being wrong mostly, then you also say "the same happens with other attributes" So is it just the images, or titles etc too?

Comment: @AnkurKhandelwal dude thanx a lot. setting holder.setIsRecyclable(false) did the trick. But is it the right approach? I mean the recyclerView is meant to recycle the child views (i guess for memory optimization). Also why does this happens in the first place? Can you help me more in this  matter.

Comment: @weston yeah it happens whereever i use the recycler view. and i don't know how the MCVE could help me in this matter cause the only case i can remove the problem is by not changing the attributes. Well yeah holder.setIsRecyclable(false) did the trick. and yep i guess i am manipulation the list where i use the adapter class i.e in my newsfeed activity.

Comment: Yeah, `holder.setIsRecyclable(false)` because now you are not recycling the views. You haven't solved the problem, just avoided it.

Comment: "the only case I can remove the problem is by not changing the attributes" Your task when making an MCVE is not to remove the problem, it's to find the smallest code that exhibits the behavior so that the issue sticks out more.

Comment: @weston yeah i agree that i am just avoiding the problem but i got no other choice.  As far as mcve is concerned, i don't know if i could ignore any bit of code. Moreover it involves 4 classes so thats complicated.

Comment: Exactly, it's too complicated. It's too hard to spot the issue, and the issue could be in one of the other classes. To start an MCVE, start a new project, add bits of this until it shows the problem. Remove anything that is unnecessary, then update the question. People can then see every piece of code that went into the problem and nothing that is superfluous to the problem.

Comment: Well thanx @weston...  There is always a next version. I guess i will try that in next version. This time i have a deadline. 

Comment: @Ashu i don't know what is the issue. I searched a lot, try adding removing function but didn't able to find the exact problem. But it think this problem happens when we tried to apply more rules in the recyclerview.  If you get the problem let me also know. thanks

Comment: @ankurkhandelwal i will tell you if i find smthg